# Reverse spline interpolation

Tags: optimization, interpolation, spline

Say I have a number of sets $(x, y)$ for $x \in \{0, 1, \dots, 255\}$. I want to find the least number of points to reproduce the set with a certain accuracy using linear interpolation. What is the mathematical method called to do this minimizing reverse spline interpolation?

Comment: I find your question hard to understand. How are $(x,y)$ a number of sets? Do you mean you have a *set* of *points* $(x,y)$? And how does a smaller number of points "reproduce" a set?

Comment: Let me rephrase,  suppose I have for each set i the set y= Ci e^x,  where Ci is a constant for each different set. I am looking for a way to find the least amount of points to linearly interpolate all sets with a certain error. I am trying to compress each set so to say.

Comment: With your original post, I thought I understand the question as "Given a set of points (xi, yi), how to find the least number of points from which the linear interpolation of them will approximate the points to a certain accuracy?" If this is indeed what your question is, the problem can be solved by fitting a degree 1 B-spline to your data points. However, with your rephrased comment, I am lost as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). It takes an arbitrary polygon curve and simplifies it according to some given precision.